# Pagination list from array

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, pagination

Hi from sql i take array and create product list. It is currently displaying a list to me, but I want to limit the number of display items and use pagination. I created the code but clicking next does not show the next items. Changes the link to domain.com/name/2 but the items are still the same. When I am on domain.com/name/2 click next does not move to domain.com/name/3 and stays on domain.com/name/2, additionally on domain.com/name/2 the previous button is not shown. My link to page is domain.com/name/ maybe here is the problem? I will be grateful for your help

```html
<?php

$page = $_GET['page'];
if (empty($page) || is_numeric($page) == FALSE) {
  $page = 1;
}
else {
  $page = $_GET['page'];
}
$items = 2;
$offset = ($page * $items) - $items;

global $wpdb;
$table = "items";
$names = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT Name FROM $table LIMIT $items OFFSET $offset");
$numbers = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT Number_it FROM $table LIMIT $items OFFSET $offset");

foreach (array_combine($numbers, $names) as $number => $name )
{
 echo '<p>'.$name.' <a href="name.php?product='.$number.'">'.$number.'</a></p>';
};
?>

<a href="domain.com/name/?page=<?php echo $page + 1; ?>">Next Page</a>
<?php if ($page != 1) { ?>
<a href="domain.com/name/?page=<?php echo $page - 1; ?>">Previous Page</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: are you sure `$_GET['page']` is what you think it is `/2` instead of `?page=2` probably requires some Htaccess work.  For example your links are this way `<a href="domain.com/name/?page=<?php echo $page + 1; ?>">` -- So which is it `domain.com/name/2` or `domain.com/name/?page=2`

Comment: do you have any proofs?

Comment: There are also a lot of "minor" bugs in your code like this `<?php echo $page + 1; ?>` on the last page, you will have one extra 'next' button that points to a page that doesn't exist.  This thing at the top `$page = $_GET['page']; if (empty($page) || is_numeric($page) == FALSE) { ... }` could be re-written to be more concise.  `$page = (empty($_GET['page']) || !is_numeric($_GET['page'])) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];` as you have it your still open to undefined index issues.  This `<?php if ($page != 1) { ?>` is pointless as `empty($page)` will catch `0` values and change them to `1`.  etc....

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ?page=2 in my site is automatic changed to /2 But I wondering if the failure of the code does not result from wrong reading of the link. But how do you check any ideas?

Comment: These 2 SQL queries, combine data `array_combine` but there is no physical relationship between them, so you are relying solely on the order they are stored in.  Which is probably a really bad idea...  As you really have no grantee that the 2 records are related. Not to mention `array_combine` will wipe out any duplicates on the first array, and throw a fatal error if the 2 arrays are not the same size etc...  This my work now, but as your DB ages you will likely have issues.  One misplaced row in there and you will be combining things you don't want to with no obvious errors.